# How to use limit and offset to restrict the data by content resolver (android)?

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider, mediastore, android-contentresolver

```
 Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
 String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID, MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_MODIFIED};

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                         // Sort function
                        bundle.putStringArray(
                                ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SORT_COLUMNS,
                                new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_MODIFIED}
                        );
                        bundle.putInt(
                                ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_SORT_DIRECTION,
                                ContentResolver.QUERY_SORT_DIRECTION_DESCENDING
                        );
                        bundle.putInt(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_LIMIT, limit);
                        bundle.putInt(ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_OFFSET, offset);
                        cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, bundle, null);
                    } else {
                        cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                                null, null
                                , MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED + " DESC " + " LIMIT " + limit + " OFFSET " + offset, null);

                    }
```

I am using this query to get images restricted by limit and offset. Though no matter what, this is always returning a cursor count of 4546. that means the data is not at all limited and the query is not working properly.

Comment: `ContentResolver.QUERY_ARG_LIMIT` Isnt there a MediaStore.QUERY_ARG_LIMIT? You are dealing wirh the media store to begin with.

Comment: Your post is missing a `mediastore` tag. Also you talk about content resolver in the subject of your post. But the content resolver cannot be blamed. Only the media store that you query.

Comment: okay i added the tag, also i have checked there is nothing like MediaStore.QUERY_ARG_LIMIT

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update : you need to add this before passing uri to cursor.

```
Uri queryUri = 
uri.buildUpon().encodedQuery("limit="+offset+","+limit).build();

// now pass uri                        
cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(queryUri, projection, bundle, null);
```